# Query about Exclusions

Tags: plotting

I guess this has already be answered.

```
Plot[1/(x^3 - 2 x^2), {x, -2, 4}, Exclusions -> True]

Plot[1/(x^3 - 2 x^2), {x, -2, 4}, Exclusions -> 2]
```

I cannot understand why I have to specify the position of discontinuity (2nd plot) in order to get rid of the vertical line at x=2 (which exists in the first plot).
Exclusions->True is not for detect the position of discontinuities?
The function is rather simple.

Comment: Does plotting $\frac1{x-2}$ have the same problem?

Comment: So, this is is considered a "normal" behavior?

Comment: I don't know; I'm not on a computer. That's why I'm asking about the result. If the same problem shows up, at least we have a simpler example of the failure of `Exclusions`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., yes same problem with `1/(x-2)`. - dimitris, Here is the advice on how to do it from the docs (`Plot` > "Options" > "Exclusions"): `Plot[1/(x^3 - x + 1), {x, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> {x^3 - x + 1 == 0}]`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis: Sorry, I didn't understand. I apologize. Yes, even for the simpler function 1/(x--2) Exclusions-True has the same behavior.

Comment: @Micheal E2: Thanks for the answer. But. still it looks curious to me that the Exclusion->True fails to detect the discontinuity.

Comment: @dimitris I think it doesn't try.  I also think `x == 0` is not excluded per se -- the plot just goes beyond the `PlotRange` and re-enters on the same side.  It would be nice if `Exclusions -> All` would call `NSolve` or do something extra.  It does not seem to.

Comment: So, are there any real examples where Exclusions -> All or /and Exclusions->True do indeed detect discontinuities?

Comment: I think for `Exclusions`, the settings `All` and `True` are synonymous with `Automatic`. In the trace, `foo = Trace[Plot[1/(x^3 - 2 x^2), {x, -2, 4}, Exclusions -> True], TraceInternal -> True];`, this happens: ``If[Graphics`PerformanceTuningDump`exclusions === All ||  Graphics`PerformanceTuningDump`exclusions === True, Graphics`PerformanceTuningDump`exclusions = Automatic]``.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Plot` seems to only do exclusions automatically for certain functions, such as `Piecewise` and some functions with branch cuts.  For algebraic functions it seems to require an equation be passed to the `Exclusions` options.

I suspect that `Plot` determines exclusions in the same way as mesh points, by tracking when a zero is crossed.  It seems simple enough to make an equation that defines which points are to be excluded:

```
Plot[f, {x, a, b}, Exclusions -> {1/f == 0}]
```

If you like, you can put this in a wrapper:

```
ClearAll[addExcl];
SetAttributes[addExcl, HoldAll];
addExcl[Plot[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts___?OptionQ]] :=
  Plot[f, {x, a, b}, Exclusions -> Flatten@{Thread[1/f == 0]}, opts]
```

Examples:

```
addExcl@Plot[Tan[x]/(x^3 - 2 x^2), {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
addExcl@Plot[{Tan[x]/(x^3 - 2 x^2), 1/(1 - Log[x])}, {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @dimitris You're welcome. :)